# Remove single quote from SQL query passed as a python string

Tags: sqlite, python

Good day. I am using flask, and I'm passing a string from app.py into a SQL database. However, Sqlite3 passed in the query along with the string, resulting in a strange result.

This is the code:

```
symbol_validity["symbol"] = 'NFLX'
    
add_stock = db.execute("SELECT ? FROM stocks", symbol_validity["symbol"])
```

Flask runs this on the database:

```
SELECT 'NFLX' FROM stocks
```

instead of:

```
SELECT NFLX FROM stocks
```

The addition of the single quotes in the query gives a weird result that isn't even a column in the database:

```
+--------+
| 'NFLX' |
+--------+
| NFLX   |
| NFLX   |
+--------+
```

How do I remove the single quote from the transferred string in the query?

Comment: It doesn't run `SELECT 'NFLX' FROM stocks` it runs `SELECT ? FROM stocks` and binds the value to the `?` placeholder. It's not a weird result at all, it's exactly what you asked: for each row please give me the placeholder value. You cannot use dynamic column names like that, you would need to build your query dynamically in Python. Make sure to escape the column name correctly

Comment: How do I build the query dynamically in Python?

Comment: If you are *sure* that the column name does not come from user input and will not cause injection then you can just concatenate it into the string. Otherwise you need techniques such as `QUOTENAME` to escape it properly